# Create NavBar programmatically with Button and Title Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I try to create a NavBar, so far the NavBar is no problem but when I try to add the buttons and title, they don't get displayed

My NavBar look like

```
let NameHeight = screenHeight * 0.09
let NameWidth = screenWidth
let navBar: UINavigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: NameWidth, height: NameHeight))
self.view.addSubview(navBar)
```

so i try to set my NavBar title like

```
navigationBar.topItem.title = "some title"
or
navigationBar.title = "some title"
```

but both fail.
Also if i try to set a button

```
let btnName = UIButton()
btnName.setImage(UIImage(named: "imagename"), forState: .Normal)
btnName.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
btnName.addTarget(self, action: Selector("action"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

//.... Set Right/Left Bar Button item
let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem()
rightBarButton.customView = btnName
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
```

this does not give me a error but the button is simply not displayed

Answer (score 72, accepted):

**Updated for Swift 5**

Create a navigation item instance and set title and right/left buttons to it. After navigation item is configured add it to the navigation bar.

```
let navBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 44))
view.addSubview(navBar)

let navItem = UINavigationItem(title: "SomeTitle")
let doneItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(selectorName:))
navItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneItem

navBar.setItems([navItem], animated: false)
```

Comment: thanks this already work :-) but still the "set custom image" fails for me could you give me a hint on this?

Comment: let doneItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: image1, landscapeImagePhone: nil, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: "Action1:") 

did solved it

Comment: For the navigation bar width you should be using the view width and not setting it to 320 - should be

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan - I think check whether the UIViewController's navigationItem is not nil. If so, then use that as "navItem", instead of adding a new navBar and navItem. Add UIBarButtonItems to that existing navigationItem. Methods like `leftBarButtonItems` on UINavigationItem.

Comment: Thanks. I will check.

Comment: I keep getting this error: "Cannot find 'view' in scope"

Answer (score 35):

Basically azimov's answer in **Swift 4**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setNavigationBar()
}

func setNavigationBar() {
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let navBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: 44))
    let navItem = UINavigationItem(title: "")
    let doneItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.done, target: nil, action: #selector(done))
    navItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneItem
    navBar.setItems([navItem], animated: false)
    self.view.addSubview(navBar)
}

@objc func done() { // remove @objc for Swift 3

}
```

Comment: Indeed this is working fine for the swift 4. The bar will be added. But it seems that height property is not working at all? No matter what kind of height you provide within the CGRect, the height of the navbar will be always same. Any ideas?

Comment: I assume that this is because you create an instance of `UINavigationBar `. if you want a more flexible solution, you would have to go with a `UIView`, but then you'll lose the given attributes like title and `setItems `

Comment: my best advice: look at `github` if you can find a framework that provides a `UINavigationBar` clone made out of a `UIView`. usually you can find stuff like that made open source by other devs

Comment: That make sense. Valuable explanation to be honest. In my case, i went with default height which was enough for mo.

Comment: The above code may cause layout issues. Instead of UIScreen.main.bounds, one should use the safe area insets to support Face ID devices. Use `self.view.safeAreaInsets.top` after viewDidAppear(_:) for the y-position of the frame and `self.view.frame.width` for the width.

Comment: @RLoniello true now. When I wrote it wasn't an (imminent) issue :) Good callout

Comment: NavigationBar are Crop on top for safe area

Comment: The answer is almost 5 years old. Obviously some stuff has changed...