# How to create and change size height navigation bar iOS 11

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch

they don't work!.

```
// Add bar button item

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var customBar: UINavigationBar = UINavigationBar()
    title = "Some Title"

    self.customBar.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:view.frame.width, height:(navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)! + 50)

    self.customBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

    self.view.addSubview(customBar)

}
```

thanks for helping!!!

Comment: is your view controller embedded in a navigation controller? if yes use self.navigationController?.navigationBar

Comment: i want to  create navigationBar by code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create NavBar programmatically with Button and Title Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33717698/create-navbar-programmatically-with-button-and-title-swift)

Comment: i can't change navigationBar height.

Comment: the first problem with your code is you have declared customBar locally and referenced it with self. `var customBar` is redundant

Comment: I edited my code,the problem of height adjustment has not yet been resolved

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Such a view controller also must be embedded in a navigation controller whether using auto layouts or programmatically and change the size preferably in the first view controller of that navigation controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't change it - not supported anymore. Here's the quote from [Apple staff](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88202#274620)

> Resizing the navigation bar (via any method, including subclassing) is
>   not supported, and neither is changing the frame of a navigation bar
>   that is owned by a UINavigationController (the navigation controller
>   will happily stomp on your frame changes whenever it deems fit to do
>   so). The navigation bar needs to be placed on the bottom edge of
>   the status bar, not underlapping the status bar, and with its natural
>   height.Finally, the internal layout of the
>   navigation bar is an implementation detail *including all class names
>   and orderings*. Any code that relies upon the ordering of the
>   navigation bar's subviews or the names of any of their classes is
>   likely to encounter issues in the future, as these are all private
>   details. Please do not rely upon them. If there are things you want to
>   do with a navigation bar that you cannot

A walk around is to use the image view then change its height.